# Having trouble integrating the React Virtuoso virtualization library into a React project with MUI components

Tags: typescript, material-ui, autocomplete, react-window, react-virtuoso

I'm trying to integrate `react-virtuoso`'s [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.dev/virtuoso-api-reference/#!) into my TypeScript web app's [MUI Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete) dropdown menu popper in order to virtualize a list of checkable options. I tried using `react-window`'s VariableSizeList at first but was having some issues with options in the list visually overlapping, I think because that lib may have an issue with list items' (both options' and option group headers') height computations. Basically, after adapting from `react-window`, my Virtuoso component isn't rendering at all.

I'm using a custom "ListBoxComponent" prop for the Autocomplete's popper, and am doing so by:

- Defining a "ListBox" component returning a div with a forwarded ref prop, which wraps a context provider, which wraps the below Virtuoso

  - Where itemData is an array of `React.ReactNode`, itemContent is the function `(index: number, item: React.ReactElement) => item`, and the other props were tried absent/not-absent when the Virtuoso still did not render
  - I also tried setting itemContent to `(index: number, data: React.ReactElement[]) => data[index]` in case I was misunderstanding the function signature.

```js
<Virtuoso
          data={itemData}
          totalCount={ELE_PER_PAGE}
          initialTopMostItemIndex={0}
          overscan={150}
          itemContent={renderItem}
        />
```

- Setting `const ListboxComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>(Listbox)`

Below is the Autocomplete

- Whose props I haven't mentioned work fine in a `react-window` ListBox

```js
<Autocomplete
      disableCloseOnSelect
      disabled={props.status !== 'success'}
      fullWidth
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      isOptionEqualToValue={getOptionSelected}
      groupBy={(option) => option.group || ''}
      id='lists'
      includeInputInList
      inputValue={input}
      limitTags={-1}
      ListboxComponent={
        ListboxComponent as React.ComponentType<
          React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>
        >
      }
      multiple
      onClose={() => {
        setInput('')
        props.prune()
      }}
      onChange={onChange}
      onInputChange={(event, value, reason) => {
        if (reason !== 'reset') {
          setInput(value)
        }
      }}
      options={getOptions}
      renderGroup={renderGroup}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          error={props.status === 'error'}
          label={`Lists (${selectedCount})`}
          variant='standard'
        />
      )}
      renderOption={renderOption}
      renderTags={() => null}
      size='small'
      value={[props.options.option]}
    />
```

Has anyone gotten `react-virtuoso` to reliably work? If so how do you typically peer into any issues with it? Perhaps it's time to figure out if one can use VSCode to directly debug React even on a containerized project (which is more complex to start than a local React proj, which might just need `npm start`).

Thank you.